# How to identify single instance of Wordpress default text widget?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to use the default WordPress text widget to the sidebar of pages where the title of the widget would dynamically change to add the title of the pages.

So I used the following code in my functions file:

```
  function my_widget_title($title, $instance, $id_base) {

  if ( is_singular() && 'text' == $id_base) {
    return get_the_title($post->ID).__(' Custom Tour Inquiry');
    }
    else {
    return $title;
    }

  } 

  add_filter ( 'widget_title' , 'my_widget_title', 10, 3);
```

This surely does what it is supposed to do, but it changes the titles of all other text widgets I try to use as well.

Is there any way I can pinpoint to one particular widget where this code will apply while the other text widgets will "behave normally"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give the widget a specific name like "My Dynamic Text Widget". Then add detection of that title as a condition in your code like the following:

```
function my_widget_title($title, $instance, $id_base) {

  if ( is_singular() && 'text' == $id_base && $title == 'My Dynamic Text Widget') {
    return get_the_title($post->ID).__(' Custom Tour Inquiry');
    }
    else {
    return $title;
    }

  } 

add_filter ( 'widget_title' , 'my_widget_title', 10, 3);
```

Comment: @Ranadeep - You're very welcome :). Sometimes when you've been solving a problem too long it's good to get someone to look in from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your code with following one. I just added `global $post` to your code to get access to the specific post.

```
function my_widget_title($title, $instance, $id_base) 
{

    global $post;
    if ( is_singular() && 'text' == $id_base) {
        return get_the_title($post->ID).__(' Custom Tour Inquiry');
    }
    else 
    {
        return $title;
    }

}
add_filter ( 'widget_title' , 'my_widget_title', 10, 3);
```

Hope this will work for you as well.

Comment: The selected code may generate a Warning for accessing $post variable without decalring it. Or object $post doesnot have the property or method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete solution according to your situation. Kindly replace your old code with this new code and get your required result.

This will add checkbox into text widget and if you check this it will replace the title otherwise normal title will be render.

```
function kk_in_widget_form($t,$return,$instance){
    if($t->id_base == "text"){
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '', 'text' => '', 'float' => 'none') );
        ?>
        <p>
            <input id="<?php echo $t->get_field_id('change_title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $t->get_field_name('change_title'); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked(isset($instance['change_title']) ? $instance['change_title'] : 0); ?> />
            <label for="<?php echo $t->get_field_id('change_title'); ?>"><?php _e('Change Title'); ?></label>
        </p>
        <?php
        $retrun = null;
    }

    return array($t,$return,$instance);
}

function kk_in_widget_form_update($instance, $new_instance, $old_instance){
    $instance['change_title'] = isset($new_instance['change_title']);
    return $instance;
}

add_action('in_widget_form', 'kk_in_widget_form',5,3);
//Callback function for options update (priorität 5, 3 parameters)
add_filter('widget_update_callback', 'kk_in_widget_form_update',5,3);
function my_widget_title($title, $instance, $id_base) {
  if ( is_singular() && 'text' == $id_base && $instance['change_title']) {
    return get_the_title($post->ID).__(' Custom Tour Inquiry');
    }
    else {
    return $title;
    }

} 

add_filter ( 'widget_title' , 'my_widget_title', 10, 3);
```

Here is backend checkbox screen
[image]